Jest failed at queryString using yarn/ Error:Cannot use import statement outside a module
I am currently facing an issue with queryString package using yarn. After reinstalling queryString using npm (In yarn documentation, there is no such command to add queryString package only npm). Still getting errors on:
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
import "../styles.css";

import queryString from "query-string";

import { StringifyOptions } from "query-string/base";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

Any workaround for this kind of situation? Please advice.
Trying to resolve queryString import issue. After reinstalling using npm, I am expecting the reinstall should resolve the issue.

If you are writing test scripts, then for some packages you need to mock before using it,
jest.mock('query-string', () => ({
  parse: jest.fn(() => ({ foo: 'bar', abc: 'xyz' })),
  stringify: jest.fn(),
  // Add other methods you need to mock here
}));

Above is just an example, you just replace parse/stringify with the methods of query-string package
